# Como usar JavaScript para manipular dados a partir de banco de dados?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, banco-de-dados

Estou começando agora a lidar com desenvolvimento web em PHP. Sabemos que para ter um sistema eficiente e dinâmico, o recomendável é utilizar JavaScript, como, JQuery, AngularJS, Backbone.js e dentro outros. Mas pelo o que conheço do Javascipt, não possui um API para conectar ao banco de dados.

Tenho um sistema para desenvolver em PHP para manipular dados a partir do banco. Nesse caso preciso "pegar" os dados no banco e gerar um gráfico, utilizando por exemplo a API do Google Charts. A primeira coisa que pensei, é manipular código JavaScript com o PHP, ou seja, colocar as *tags* JavaScript dentro do código PHP (código para conectar ao banco de dados) e obter os dados e inserir no JavaScript. Porém, essa não seria uma boa prática de programação, pois, meu código ficaria ilegível de se manipular e eu teria problemas futuros com o meu sistema.

Gostaria de obter de programadores experientes em como contornar essa situação. Basicamente, como eu posso manipular dados a partir do banco de dados em JavaScript, AngularJS, Google Charts e etc. e como posso obter uma boa integração entre programação PHP e JavaScript, assim como outros linguagens com JavaScript.

Comment: Já que sitou AngularJS e BackboneJS, te aconselho a criar um [Serviço REST em PHP](http://coreymaynard.com/blog/creating-a-restful-api-with-php/) que retorne um [JSON](http://www.json.org), então chame a sua API/Serviço usando [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) para então criar o seu grafico.

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 7):

Acredito que esteja colocando o carro na frente dos bois. Você não escolhe a tecnologia que vai usar e depois vê qual problema vai resolver. Por isso fez a afirmação inicial que não tem sentido algum:

> Sabemos que para ter um sistema eficiente e dinâmico, o recomendável é utilizar JavaScript, como, JQuery, AngularJS, Backbone.js e dentro outros

Isto está completamente incorreto. Justamente porque acha que a tecnologia é que é importante.

O JavaScript até pode ser usado para acessar um "banco de dados" local, mas provavelmente não é o que você quer. O JS também pode ser usado através do Node.js no servidor para acessar um banco de dados, mas também não é o que quer.

Então se vai acessar um banco de dados no servidor faça com PHP e estabeleça comunicação entre o cliente e o servidor com tecnologias web. Se o JS puder (nem sempre é o certo) ajudar a dar uma experiência melhor nesta comunicação, então use ele no cliente para facilitar.

Tenha certo de que você não coloca JS algum dentro do PHP. Você apenas coloca um texto qualquer no PHP, que por acaso você sabe que é um código JS, mas isto será enviado para o cliente e não será executado pelo PHP. Não é questão de ser ilegível, ele não é factível. Além de ser ilegível e esdrúxulo.

Primeiro garanta que o lado do servidor está obtendo os dados que precisa. Depois faça um teste básico onde o cliente pega estes dados da forma mais simples possível, só usando HTML. Depois comece sofisticar usando técnicas onde o JavaScript é usado, com ou sem *frameworks*.

Como a pergunta está cheia de falsas premissas, fica difícil ajudar mais, mas é possível postar novas perguntas com dúvidas específicas em cada etapa da solução desejada.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Conceptual.md).